# Concurrent producer/consumer queue design for different class types

Tags: c++, types, collections, concurrency, queue

I have two threads running, where the producer thread enqueues the concurrent queue (https://github.com/cameron314/readerwriterqueue.git) with different types of updates and a consumer thread which dequeues updates and executes different code paths based on the update type. These updates have to be processed in the correct order.

I do not want to use any additional dependencies that can't be quickly linked via CMake FetchContent.

I came up with this, but i am wondering if there is a better way to do this :

```
enum UpdateType {
    A,
    B
};

class Update {
    const std::shared_ptr<DataA> _dataA;
    const std::shared_ptr<DataB> _dataB;
    UpdateType _type;
public:
    Update(std::shared_ptr<DataA> dataA) : _dataA(std::move(dataA)) {
        _type = A;
    }
    Update(std::shared_ptr<DataB> dataB) : _dataB(std::move(dataB)) {
        _type = B;
    }
    UpdateType GetType() const { return _type; }
    std::shared_ptr<DataA> GetA() const { return _dataA; }
    std::shared_ptr<DataB> GetB() const { return _dataB; }
};

auto queue = moodycamel::BlockingReaderWriterQueue<std::shared_ptr<Update>>(200);

Update a(std::make_shared<DataA>(DataA()));
Update b(std::make_shared<DataB>(DataB()));

queue.enqueue(std::make_shared<Update>(a));
queue.enqueue(std::make_shared<Update>(b));

std::shared_ptr<Update> q;
queue.wait_dequeue(q);

switch (q->GetType())
{
case A:
    // Process A
    break;
case B:
    // Process B
    break;
}
```

Comment: You can use a [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: Thank you, i went with Igors approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps:

```
void ProcessA(std::shared_ptr<DataA> data);
void ProcessB(std::shared_ptr<DataB> data);

using UnitOfWork = std::function<void()>;
auto queue = moodycamel::BlockingReaderWriterQueue<UnitOfWork>(200);

// Producer
auto dataA = std::make_shared<DataA>();
queue.enqueue([dataA]() { ProcessA(dataA); });
auto dataB = std::make_shared<DataB>();
queue.enqueue([dataB]() { ProcessB(dataB); });

// Consumer
UnitOfWork w;
queue.wait_dequeue(w);
w();
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, this approach works great.